# Macro that declare variables in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

In C its possible to write a macro that declares variables, as follows:

```
#define VARS(a, b, c) \
    int a, b, c;
```

Of course this isn't something you'd typically want to do.

In the actual example I'm looking to get working its not quite so simple.

```
#define VARS(data, stride, a, b, c) \
    MyStruct *a = &data.array[0],            \
    MyStruct *b = &data.array[1 * (stride)], \
    MyStruct *c = &data.array[2 * (stride)];
```

However the exact details of assignment shouldn't matter for the purpose of this question.

Is it possible to write a macro like this in Rust?
If so how would this be written?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible to write such a macro in Rust:

```
macro_rules! vars {
    ($data:expr, $stride:expr, $var1:ident, $var2:ident, $var3:ident) => {
        let $var1 = $data[0];
        let $var2 = $data[1 * $stride];
        let $var3 = $data[2 * $stride];
    };
}

fn main() {
    let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let stride = 2;
    vars!(array, stride, a, b, c);
    println!("{}", a);
    println!("{}", b);
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

Read the [Macros chapter in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/macros.html) for more information.

Comment: The macros chapter in the new book [is here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-06-macros.html).