# Lifetime constraints on a macro returning a value

Tags: rust, macros, lifetime

In the following code the `fun` function and the `mac` macro do the same thing:

```
struct S<'s> {
    src: &'s str,
    off: usize,
}
impl std::fmt::Debug for S<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "* {}", &self.src[self.off..])
    }
}

fn fun<'s>(value: &'s str) -> S<'s> {
    let s = S{ src: value, off: 1 };
    s
}

/// The real macro is variadic, that's why it can't be replaced with a function
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! mac {
    ($value: expr) => {{
        let s = S{ src: $value, off: 1 };
        // there should be more here
        s
    }};
}

pub fn main() {
   let p = std::path::PathBuf::from("hi"); 

   // works OK
   dbg!(fun(&p.to_string_lossy()));

   // works ok
   let temp = p.to_string_lossy();
   dbg!(mac!(&temp));

   // can't be compiled
   dbg!(mac!(&p.to_string_lossy()));
}
```

But the macro can't be called as easily. The last line of code can't be compiled.

How could I fix the macro to avoid the "temporary which is freed while still in use" problem, so that macro users don't have to create uselessly verbose temporary variables ?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21b5b8dcd995dc626449765acbe402ec)

Comment: do you need the reference? A non-ideal solution would perhaps be to make the macro consume `p.to_string_lossy()`

Comment: @lucidbrot the macro uses an object (S) which is very complex and reference based (so that it doesn't copy things). I can't really change the object and I understand why it's difficult. What I'm looking at is a trick to make the lifetime rules which apply to the function call apply to the macro call.

Comment: `to_string_lossy` returns a `Cow`, who do you want the owner of this to be in the last example?

Comment: I see. The problem is clear to you, right? With the `let`, the reference exists until the end of `main`. Without, it only exists until the end of the macro, which means that `S` would reference something that no longer exists.

Comment: In fact a solution could probably be to make the macro call different functions depending on the number of arguments. But this would be a horrible macro...

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! mag {
    ($value: expr) => {
        ($value, S{ src: &$value, off: 1 })

    };
}

pub fn main() {
   let p = std::path::PathBuf::from("hi"); 
   dbg!(mag!(p.to_string_lossy()).0);
}
```

---

I have found a solution, inspired by [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38780056/2550406):

```
struct S<'s> {
    src: &'s str,
    off: usize,
}
impl std::fmt::Debug for S<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "* {}", &self.src[self.off..])
    }
}

fn fun<'s>(value: &'s str) -> S<'s> {
    let s = S{ src: value, off: 1 };
    s
}

/// The real macro is variadic, that's why it can't be replaced with a function
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! mac {
    ($value: expr) => {{
        let s = S{ src: $value, off: 1 };
        // there should be more here
        s
    }};
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! macc {
    ($value: expr, $var0:ident, $var1:ident) => {
        let $var1 = $value;
        let $var0 = S{ src: &$var1, off: 1 };
        // there should be more here

    };
}

pub fn main() {
   let p = std::path::PathBuf::from("hi"); 

   // works OK
   dbg!(fun(&p.to_string_lossy()));

   // works ok
   let temp = p.to_string_lossy();
   dbg!(mac!(&temp));

   // CAN be compiled
   macc!(p.to_string_lossy(), alpha, beta);
   dbg!(alpha);
}
```

I define a macro `macc` instead of your `mac`. It takes some identifiers that then become available in your calling scope (i.e. within `main()`).
That way, the macro can `let beta` with it staying in scope. This is so that the macro does not create unexpected identifiers, overwriting existing variable names.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a383cfbcbfa31e82a0545082fb5a73ad)

---

If the macro is [defined within the same function](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3owg82/is_it_possible_to_tell_rust_to_relax_its_macro/), you can get rid of one of the two identifier arguments:

```
pub fn main() {
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! maccc {
    ($value: expr, $var0:ident) => {
        let my_own_thing = $value;
        let $var0 = S{ src: &my_own_thing, off: 1 };
        // there should be more here

    };
}
   let p = std::path::PathBuf::from("hi"); 

   // works when maccc is defined within the function
   maccc!(p.to_string_lossy(), gamma);
   dbg!(gamma);
}
```

---

## I think I got it as good as it gets:

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b375b930672d981070995bf1131144e5)

```
struct S<'s> {
    src: &'s str,
    off: usize,
}
impl std::fmt::Debug for S<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "* {}", &self.src[self.off..])
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! mag {
    ($value: expr) => {
        ($value, S{ src: &$value, off: 1 })

    };
}

pub fn main() {
   let p = std::path::PathBuf::from("hi"); 

   // works
   let (_,m) = mag!(p.to_string_lossy());
   dbg!(m);
}
```

This returns a tuple with the temporary value and `s`, so that the temporary value does not yet go out of scope. You can even do it this way:

```
   // works
   let m = mag!(p.to_string_lossy()).0;
   dbg!(m);
```

Comment: This isn't quite as ergonomic as the function solution

Comment: That is true. It's the best I have found until now, but I am not that experienced with rust macros. Perhaps you find something better

Comment: @DenysSéguret See the end of my answer for a solution that allows you to return something. It also returns the input expression, so that it is not out of scope yet